# How To Update Exchange365 Autoreplies Using Graph API In PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to update user autoreply (out of office) mailbox settings in Exchange.  I have all the authentication code in place and it works.  Now I just need to tell what to update.

The C# example is:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var mailboxSettings = new MailboxSettings
{
    AutomaticRepliesSetting = new AutomaticRepliesSetting
    {
        Status = AutomaticRepliesStatus.Scheduled,
        ScheduledStartDateTime = new DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = "2016-03-20T18:00:00",
            TimeZone = "UTC"
        },
        ScheduledEndDateTime = new DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = "2016-03-28T18:00:00",
            TimeZone = "UTC"
        }
    }
};

var me = new User();
me.MailboxSettings = mailboxSettings;

await graphClient.Me
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(me);
```

I'm not sure how to translate that into PHP using the Graph API.  I have tried to find document on how to do this with the PHP API but have been unsuccessful.

This is the PHP code I came up with:

```
include "../../vendor/autoload.php";
$code=$_GET["code"];

use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;


$oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
      'clientId'                => "clientid",
      'clientSecret'            => "secret",
      'redirectUri'             => "redirect",
      'urlAuthorize'            => "auth",
      'urlAccessToken'          => "access",
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
      'scopes'                  => 'offline_access MailboxSettings.ReadWrite'
    ]);

try {
  // Make the token request
  $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
    'code' => $code
  ]);

  $token=$accessToken->getToken();
  $graph = new Graph();
  $graph->setAccessToken($token);

  $user = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me/mailboxSettings')
            ->setReturnType(Model\MailboxSettings::class)
            ->execute();

  $mailboxSettings = new Model\MailboxSettings();
  $start=new Model\DateTimeTimeZone();
  $start->DateTime = "2019-07-03T18:00:00";
  $start->TimeZone = "America/New_York";
  $end=new Model\DateTimeTimeZone();
  $end->DateTime = "2019-07-04T18:00:00";
  $end->TimeZone = "America/New_York";

  $replySettings = new Model\AutomaticRepliesSetting($propDict);
  $replySettings->setStatus(Model\AutomaticRepliesStatus::SCHEDULED);
  $replySettings->setScheduledStartDateTime($start);
  $replySettings->setScheduledEndDateTime($end);
  $replySettings->setInternalReplyMessage("I'm out of the office");
  $replySettings->setExternalReplyMessage("I'm out of the office");
  $mailboxSettings->setAutomaticRepliesSetting($replySettings);
}
catch (League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
  exit('ERROR getting tokens: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

This code doesn't give me any errors but I'm not sure how to actually send an update request to update the settings.

Also, is there a way for the access token to persist?  What I'm trying to accomplish is this:
Users enter time off requests, inputting what they want their out of office message to be.  I would have a cron job running that would update their out of office message for when they are out of the office.  Is that possible?

Comment: For this issue, you can use curl in PHP to make a PATCH request. May I know if my answer helps ?

Comment: Could you give me an example on how I might do this with curl?

Comment: Updated answer, please have a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the GraphServiceClient will finally call the Microsoft Graph API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

There is an API to modify the mailbox settings. By setting the automaticRepliesSetting in it, you can modify your autoreply setting. And you can find a sample on that page:
[image]

Note:

Microsoft Graph API is protected by Azure AD. You need to get an access token first. For how to get auth token, please refer to the official tutorial: [Get auth token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/?view=graph-rest-1.0)

**Update:**

You can make a patch request as following:

```
<?php
    $token = "your get with adal php sdk";

    $authUrl      = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailboxSettings';
    $ch           = curl_init();
    $headers      = [
           "Content-Type:application/json",
           "Authorization:Bearer $token"
    ];

    $data = array(
        "@odata.context" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/\$metadata#Me/mailboxSettings",
        "automaticRepliesSetting" => array (
            "status" => "scheduled" ,
            "externalAudience" => "all",
            "scheduledStartDateTime" => array (
                "dateTime" => "2019-07-18T05:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone" => "UTC"
            ), 
            "scheduledEndDateTime" => array (
                "dateTime" => "2019-07-19T06:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone" => "UTC"
            ) ,
            "internalReplyMessage" => "This is the internalReplyMessage.",
            "externalReplyMessage" => "This is the externalReplyMessage."
        )
    );

    $postdata = json_encode($data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $strResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlErrno   = curl_errno($ch);
    if ($curlErrno) {
           $curlError = curl_error($ch);
           throw new Exception($curlError);
    }

    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
//  $objResponse = json_decode($strResponse);

    print_r($http_status."\n");
    print_r($strResponse."\n");

?>
```

**Result:**

From the outlook, I can see that the autoreply settings has been successfully updated.

[image]